# Flash Component in iPhone

Tags: iphone

i have few questions regarding flash components in iphone

1. I would like to know if a safari browser in iphone can play a flash component(swf file).
   Do i need to download a plugin for safari ? If so will the plugin update the existing safari browser or will it be another standalone application which plays the swf file in the safari browser? same doubt i have with mozilla browser in iphone.
2. I have a swf file .Will i be able to embed that to a native application in iphone.
3. I saw that iphone flash application can be developed and such applications are present in app store.If so which version of adobe flash has that capability ? (cs4 or cs5)

Comment: Questions 1 + 2 duplicate these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290047/how-to-add-a-moving-flash-in-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028653/flex-applications-for-iphone, and question 3 is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928891/native-flash-on-mobile-platforms

Answer (score 2):

The Flash plugin is not available on iPhone, and will certainly never be...
You might take a look at Adobe Flash CS5, which will be able to create native iPhone apps from AS code.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashcs5/appsfor_iphone/

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to embed a Flash SWF into your app using Hirameki. Still not ready for market, but it plays Flash animations directly from a SWF file inside a native app.

http://flash-on-iphone.com/demo